# Optimizing rendering with a lot of transformations and save/restore

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, canvas, fractals

I have implemented a renderer for shapes described with a [L-System grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). Implementation of that is not important. Basically you feed it an angle and some rules, and it spits out a string of characters that represents instructions. For example, "+" means turn right *n* radians and vice versa. The instructions will only be computed once.

The job of the method `.draw` is to read the instructions and draw it on a canvas continuously. The angle is always changing (however the instructions stay the same) and therefore this method will be called repeatedly:

```
LSystem.prototype.draw = function(ctx, x, y) {
    var self = this;
    var path = this.path;
    var table = {
        "F": function(ctx) {
            // draw forward
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(0, -5);
            ctx.translate(0, -5);
        },
        "+": function(ctx) {
            // turn right
            ctx.rotate(self.angle);
        },
        "-": function(ctx) {
            // turn left
            ctx.rotate(-self.angle);
        },
        "[": function(ctx) {
            // save location and rotation
            ctx.save();
        },
        "]": function(ctx) {
            // restore location and rotation
            ctx.restore();
        }
    };
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
    ctx.translate(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        // take a character from the path
        // and call the corresponding function (if exists)
        var char = path[i];
        var cmd = table[char];
        cmd && cmd(ctx);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
};
```

A path (in my case) consists of over 6000 characters. It has no problem in drawing at 60FPS. However the main problem is that it uses a lot of CPU and I can hear the fans in my laptop starts spinning. This is not optimal and I'm looking for a way to solve this.

By looking at the profiling tool in Chrome, we can see that it doesn't like `.rotate` and `.restore` being called repeatedly. On a 16ms budget it already takes up half of it:

[image]

What is a good way of optimizing the rendering and minimize CPU usage? Would calculating the coordinates for the entire path first then pass it to `.lineTo` be a better choice? Keep in mind that the angle is different every time `.draw` is called, so the coordinates cannot be cached and reused.

A demo can be viewed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/d4f2u66j/).

Comment: If it's graphics intensive, WebGL might be a better option since it can take advantage of the user's GPU. It has a pretty steep learning curve, but it should help dramatically.

Answer (score 4):

I see this was the second javascript question you posted here and it is unfortunate that there have been no responses in the nearly four years since then. Perhaps you have learned a few things about JavaScript since then.

Looking at the `draw` method I see that it stores a reference to `this` in a variable called `self`. This pattern happens frequently in JavaScript code but it is unnecessary. I see that some of the functions in `table` utilize `self` but that could be avoided by binding those functions to `this` with [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

It also appears that `ctx` is passed to each function as a parameter, which is also unnecessary because `ctx` is hoisted at the top-level and visible within each function as well.

The functions in `table` associated with keys `"["` and `"]"` could be simply set to `ctx.save.bind(ctx)` and `ctx.restore.bind(ctx)`, respectively. Furthermore, the functions in `table` associated with keys `"+"` and `"-"` can be set to `ctx.rotate.bind(ctx, this.angle)` and `ctx.rotate.bind(ctx, -this.angle)`, respectively.

I'm not sure if those changes will be enough to reduce the CPU load. If not, then consider taking out function calls (i.e. calling `table[char]`) and using a series of `if` statements or `switch` statement in the `for` loop.

### Demo

While it may not be much, see the demo below which hopefully provides some proof that the suggestions lead to a slight performance gain (see the `drawB()` method). I considered using jsPerf but that might be a bit of a stretch to use for this code.

```js
var rules = [
  //["F", "F[+F]F[-F]F"]

  //["F", "F+F--F+F"]

  //["1", "1F1F"],
  //["0", "1F[+0][-0]"]

  //["F", "F+F-F-F+F"]

  ["F", "FF"],
  ["X", "F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X"]
];
var angle = 10;
const times = [{
  y: [],
  line: {
    color: "blue",
    width: 4,
    shape: "line"
  },
    name: "Original draw()"
}, {
  y: [],
  line: {
    color: "green",
    width: 4,
    shape: "line"
  },
    name: "Simplified draw()"
}];

function LSystem(rules, angle, init, level) {
  this.rules = {};
  this.angle = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  this.parseRules(rules);
  this.path = this.generateLevel(init, level);
}
LSystem.prototype.parseRules = function(rules) {
  var self = this;
  rules.forEach(function(rule) {
    self.rules[rule[0]] = rule[1];
  });
};
LSystem.prototype.applyRule = function(input) {
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var char = input[i];
    if (char in this.rules) {
      output += this.rules[char];
    } else {
      output += char;
    }
  }
  return output;
};
LSystem.prototype.generateLevel = function(input, level) {
  if (level == 0) return input;
  return this.generateLevel(this.applyRule(input), level - 1);
};
LSystem.prototype.draw = function(x, y) {
  var start = +new Date();
  var self = this;
  var path = this.path;
  var table = {
    "F": function(ctx) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(5, 0);
      ctx.translate(5, 0);
    },
    "+": function(ctx) {
      ctx.rotate(self.angle);
    },
    "-": function(ctx) {
      ctx.rotate(-self.angle);
    },
    "[": function(ctx) {
      ctx.save();
    },
    "]": function(ctx) {
      //ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
      //ctx.beginPath();
    }
  };
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
  ctx.translate(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    var char = path[i];
    var cmd = table[char];
    cmd && cmd(ctx);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
  const end = +new Date();
  times[0].y.push((end - start));
  if (times[0].y.length > 1) {
    avg.innerText = times[0].y.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / times[0].y.length;
  }
};
LSystem.prototype.drawB = function(x, y) {
  var start = +new Date();
  var table = {
    "F": function() {
      ctxB.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctxB.lineTo(5, 0);
      ctxB.translate(5, 0);
    },
    "+": ctxB.rotate.bind(ctxB, this.angle),
    "-": ctxB.rotate.bind(ctxB, -this.angle),
    "[": ctxB.save.bind(ctxB),
    "]": ctxB.restore.bind(ctxB)
  };
  ctxB.save();
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctxB.beginPath();
  ctxB.moveTo(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
  ctxB.translate(x + 0.5, y + 0.5);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++) {
    var char = this.path[i];
    var cmd = table[char];
    cmd && cmd();
  }
  ctxB.stroke();
  ctxB.restore();
  const end = +new Date();
  times[1].y.push((end - start));
  if (times[1].y.length > 1) {
    avgB.innerText = times[1].y.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / times[1].y.length;
    avgB.classList.toggle('faster', parseFloat(avgB.innerText) < parseFloat(avg.innerText));
    avgB.classList.toggle('slower', parseFloat(avgB.innerText) > parseFloat(avg.innerText));
    avg.classList.toggle('faster', parseFloat(avg.innerText) < parseFloat(avgB.innerText));
    avg.classList.toggle('slower', parseFloat(avg.innerText) > parseFloat(avgB.innerText));
  }
}


// main
var ctx,
  ctxB,
  s = new LSystem(rules, angle, "X", 5),
  sB = new LSystem(rules, angle, "X", 5),
  output;
window.onload = function() {
  ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctxB = document.getElementById("cnvB").getContext("2d");
  output = document.querySelector("pre");

  ctx.translate(50, 500);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * -65);
  ctx.translate(0, -250);

  ctxB.translate(50, 500);
  ctxB.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * -65);
  ctxB.translate(0, -250);

  //ctx.translate(250, 500);
  function d(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(d);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    s.draw(0, 250);
    sB.drawB(0, 250);

    s.angle = Math.PI / 180 * (25 + Math.sin(t / 1000));
    sB.angle = Math.PI / 180 * (25 + Math.sin(t / 1000));
  }
  output.textContent = s.path.length;
  requestAnimationFrame(d);
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

output.slower {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

output.faster {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart">
  <div id="comparison"></div>
</div>
<table>
 <tr><td> Avg time for <code>draw()</code></td><td> <output id="avg"></output> ms
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
  Avg time for modified <code>draw()</code> </td><td><output id="avgB"></output> ms
</td></tr>
</table>
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="cnvB"></canvas>
<pre></pre>
```

#### Result

Below is a chart comparing the elapsed times of 100 calls to the original `draw` method and the modified `draw` method.

[image: comparison chart]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I doubt calling the functions with `.bind` with help with the performance since `.draw` is only called once per iteration. The browser would optimize it out anyway so it's probably not worth doing these micro-optimizations, though I haven't done any benchmarking on that. Taking a look at my final solution (it's on my homepage), it seems that I solved the problem simply by not calling `.rotate` and `.restore`, and instead just do the calculations myself. Saving the entire 2D context is unnecessary, so I just avoided those methods and ended with sub-ms rendering time.

Comment: okay - I have added a demo with some benchmarking to illustrate that the suggestions lead to lower average executions times for the `draw()` method - maybe not initially but eventually it becomes true.